# Invoke-WebRequest not outputting RawContentStream in script

Tags: powershell

I built a script that looks up every remote IP Address connected to my computer and returns information on it if possible. All of it works fine except

```
$serv_inf.RawContentStream
```

does not return any output when its variable is called.

Here's the script:

```
$h_list = Get-NetTCPConnection -AppliedSetting internet | Select-Object -Property RemoteAddress
$h_conv = $h_list.remoteaddress
foreach ($_ip in $h_conv) {
    if ($_ip -ne "127.0.0.1") {
        try {
            if (Invoke-WebRequest -Method Head -TimeoutSec 3 -DisableKeepAlive $_ip -ea Ignore) {
                echo "`n"
                echo "[+] NSLookup:`t$_ip`n"
                $x = nslookup $_ip
                foreach ($line in $x){
                    if ($line -ne "") {
                        echo " |--$line"
                    }
                }
                $serv_inf = Invoke-WebRequest -Method Head -TimeoutSec 5 -DisableKeepAlive $_ip -ea Ignore
                echo "-------------------------------------"
                echo "[+] Header Info:`n-------------------------------------"
                $serv_inf.Headers
                echo "-------------------------------------"
                echo "[+] Raw Content:`n-------------------------------------"
                $serv_inf.RawContent
                echo "-------------------------------------"
                echo "[+] Raw Content Stream:`n-------------------------------------`n"
                $serv_inf.RawContentStream
                echo "`n==============================================================================================" 
            }
            Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
        } catch {}
    }
}
```

The output returned looks like:

```
[+] NSLookup:   xx.xx.xx.xx

 |--Server:   xx.some.com
 |--Address:  xx.xx.xx.xx
 |--Name:     xx.other.some.com
 |--Address:  xx.xx.xx.xx
-------------------------------------
[+] Header Info:
-------------------------------------
Connection     close
Content-Length 0
Date           Fri, 11 May 2018 20:43:10 GMT
Server         Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-Powered-By   ASP.NET
-------------------------------------
[+] Raw Content:
-------------------------------------

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: close
Content-Length: 0
Date: Fri, 11 May 2018 20:43:10 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET


-------------------------------------
[+] Raw Content Stream:
-------------------------------------
```

What confuses me is if I run `$serv_inf.RawContentStream` by itself, it outputs fine:

```
-------------------------------------
[+] Raw Content Stream:
-------------------------------------



CanRead      : True
CanSeek      : True
CanTimeout   : False
CanWrite     : True
Length       : 0
Capacity     : 10000
Position     : 0
ReadTimeout  :
WriteTimeout :
```

but if I call it in this script, `$serv_inf.RawContentStream` fails to output every time. Why will it print output individually but return blank every time in the script?

**Edit:**

I set a breakpoint where `$serv_inf.RawContentStream` is supposed to be called and tried executing it myself:

```
[DBG]: PS C:\Users\xxxxxxx\Desktop\scripts\ps>> $serv_inf.RawContentStream


CanRead      : True
CanSeek      : True
CanTimeout   : False
CanWrite     : True
Length       : 0
Capacity     : 10000
Position     : 0
ReadTimeout  :
WriteTimeout :
```

I see that nothing is wrong with its contents, but I'm not sure why it's failing to show. I realize `$serv_inf.BaseResponse` has similar behavior where it will output individually but not in the script and was wondering how those were related.

Comment: Some kind of rate-limit? Why do you send the exact same request 4 times in a row anyway? Just send it once and collect the output in a variable (`$rsp = Invoke-WebRequest ...`), then use the desired property where appropriate (`$rsp.statusdescription`, `$rsp.headers`, ...).

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers you're right, I tidied that up in the code. Thank you for pointing that out! I looked further into it and it wasn't a rate limit, it's specific to certain properties though I'm not sure how they're related in this sense.